# API Data from quotes API not displaying on React app

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I am making a MonkeyType clone in React, because I really like the design and I want to practice my typing.

I decided to use a quotes API to have something to type, but I got stuck. My backup plan is to grab some mock data from chatGPT, but it is at capacity (forever?), so here I am.

I can console.log the quote list that I grab from the API using fetch (it does console.log twice, which is weird), but when I try to display the first quote from the random list, I get an error that the quote is undefined. The array structure of the quotes from the [api](https://zenquotes.io/api/quotes) is as follows:

```
[
  { q: "",
    a: "",
    h: "",
    c: "",
  },
  ...,
]
```

I actually don't have my code in front of me (I'm on my work computer), but basically make a new react project, import useState and useEffect (make an empty array for your state), so javascript is like this before the return:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(https://zenquotes.io/api/quotes).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => setQuoteList(data))
}, [])
```

Then, in the return:

```
<div>
  <p> {quoteList[0].q} </p>
</div>
```

I tried changing the structure of the quoteList so something would show up, nothing has so far. I can `console.log` the random quotes fine, I just can't display it from my state in React.

Comment: You can use map function to work with array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an object directly into JSX in react. If you change {quoteList[0].q} to {JSON.stringify(quoteList[0].q)}, it should work!